# p:spinner should take only numeric values

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spinner

I am using PrimeFaces spinner, but while I give string values, it takes the string values to bean classes, but it should accept only numeric.

```
<h:outputLabel value=" Spinner: " />
<p:spinner value="#{bean.num}" />
```

Comment: I don't see a spinner here... And did you use a number/integer as the field in the backingbean? You should and it should fail then. Try...

Comment: oh and post your PF version info (and jsf version info and implementation). It is good practice to do. As is posting a [mcve], then we might not need to ask questions but can directly answer. Cheers

Comment: okay got it  ,we are using string in backing bean